# Setting default value for Dojo datagrid

Tags: datagrid, dojo

How to set a default or startup value (empty space without dotted line) for Dojo datagrid?

When datagrid starts up I need to display a empty space. How to set it?

Answer (score 0):

I sure hope you found an answer to this already. Regardless, simply set your store to empty using the following javascript,

```
var dojoData = {"items":""};
```